# Vim macro: log/variableize selected object

Tags: vim, macros

Is there some sort of Vim plugin that would allow me to do something like this, given the code:

```
function something (arbitraryObject) {
  arbitraryObject.something = doesNotMatter;
}
```

Then let's say I just select the word `arbitraryObject` in the function body, I'd like an easy way to write a macro that, given a short key combination or command-mode command, could give me something like:

```
function something (arbitraryObject) {
  arbitraryObject.something = doesNotMatter;
  console.log(arbitraryObject);
}
```

or...

```
function something (arbitraryObject) {
  arbitraryObject.something = doesNotMatter;
  window.arbitraryObject = arbitraryObject;
}
```

Note that I'm not asking what this macro would actually look like, I'm curious if there are built-in tools or plugins that make the creation of things like this particularly easy.

Comment: That's pretty easy to achieve. It's a pity you don't want to see how it would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you aren't asking for the specific macro, but it's easiest to learn these types of things by example. The first one (console.log) can be achieved through this mapping:

```
:vmap <leader>il y<esc>oconsole.log(<c-r>");<esc>
```

Likewise, the second one could look like this:

```
:vmap <leader>iw y<esc>owindow.<c-r>" = <c-r>";<esc>
```

Can you spot the similarities? `<leader>il` means that the command binds to the leader key (usually <kbd>,</kbd>) followed by <kbd>i</kbd> followed by <kbd>l</kbd>. You can check what the following commands mean by using `:help [key]` in vim, but the mappings basically <kbd>y</kbd>ank (copy) the selected text, enters a new line (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>) and then appends some text followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd>, which inserts the yanked text.

Comment: This is the closest to what I was looking for, it's just that what bothers me is that there may be tons of these that I want for different languages (i.e. `ap` for Ruby), and for much more than logging and assignment for debugging.I wish there was something as practical as SnipMate, where I could define a macro like this, select a word, type the proper command, and have the macro performed. I guess I could do that this way, just making well-defined, namespaced, and organized shortcuts like this.

Comment: You could add a couple of auto commands ([like this](http://pastie.org/4309908)) to your vimrc for commonly used macros.

Comment: You should be using `vnoremap` here. It produces much more stable results.

Comment: And, by the way, 1. Why does user own mapping ever need `<leader>`? I never get it, using `<leader>` for plugins only. and 2. When `,` managed to became *usual* value of the leader, not the default `\`? It is true that comma is common customized value, but users keeping this as-is are more usual.

Comment: @ZyX, I believe the widespread of `:let mapleader=","` comes from [this blog post](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/). I use `<Leader>` for custom mappings because I like to have a common "interface" for every non-builtin commands: my own mappings and mappings coming from third party plugins.

Comment: Also, `,` is used as an example in `:h mapleader`; that's probably where this "trend" comes from. `<Leader>` is a feature provided "as is" with no recommendation against using it in custom mappings. The only mention of "plugins" I see there is *"In a global plugin `<Leader>` should be used and in a filetype plugin `<LocalLeader>`"* which is far from meaning that we should use `<Leader>` *only* in plugins. Custom mappings don't need `<Leader>`. Nobody says that. It's only a trend you don't agree with. Like me and using Vim tabs like if they were regular tabs. We should get over it, I guess.

Comment: @romainl 1. Thanks, I did not remember examples from documentation. 2. I did not say it *should* be used only in plugins. I said *I do not get why it is used not in plugins*. My arguments are the following: a) it obfuscates the reading: you have to remember context to get what `<Leader>` is exanded to. b) it makes mapping commands behave differently depending on their location in the vimrc. c) you get used to typing `,il`, not `<Leader>il`. d) it makes it more likely for plugins to spoil your own mappings (i.e. by direct conflict or just delay: `,c`+`,cc`), especially if they are short.

Comment: All very good arguments, I must say. I don't think a) is a big problem as `<Leader>` is either `\` or my own `,`. b) is clearly a potential problem, especially with the current trend of copy-pasting bits and pieces from different sources. c) you are right. d) I like to analyse what my plugins do before I let them settle in my `~/.vim` so this problem is mitigated but I can see how it can become frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use something like [snipMate.vim](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) and have snippets for your various tasks. For example, you could create these snippets:

```
snippet cons
  console.log(${1:variable});${2}
snippet wind
  window.${1:attribute} = $1${2}
```

Then you could do something like `yocons<Tab><C-r>"<Tab>`, or likewise `yowind<Tab><C-r>"<Tab>`. You could also use `yiw` instead of visually selecting too. I like an option like this because then you can easily make it applicable to only a particular type of filetype (e.g. javascript) and continue to extend your already existing snippets.

Comment: Gave you a vote as this is a useful method, but not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap <Leader>l o<esc>pv^"xygv[ygvdiconsole.log(<esc>a"<esc>pa",<esc>"xpa);<esc>
```

This is better alternative, since it quotes strings with help of vim-unimpared. Just yank text, you need to log and use this key binging. It converts

```
this.$el.find("input,select,textarea")
```

to

```
console.log("this.$el.find(\"input,select,textarea\")",this.$el.find("input,select,textarea"));
```